# Building a Dynamic Linq Query using Equals and an Array

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, dynamic-linq

I have been trying to solve the syntax for a dynamic linq query that is needed in my application.

I have a dynamic query that the where clause needs to be specified to either

- GuidPrimaryKey is contained in a list of Guid OR
- GuidPrimaryKey is equal to an item in a list of Guid (using some type of for-loop)

I have a Guid[] populated with over 5,000 keys.  My Query is set up as

If I do this (as a test) it is successful

```
data = data.where("GuidPrimaryKey.Equals(@0)",array[0]);
```

as well as

```
data = data.where("GuidPrimaryKey.Equals(@0) OR GuidPrimaryKey.Equals(@1)",array[0], array[1]);
```

I have tried:`data = data.where("GuidPrimaryKey.Contains(@0)",array);` but that gives an error: No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Guid'.

I also tried setting a loop to go through the elements in the array and set the where clause as a giant string, but that did not work either.

```
string s = "";
string p = ""
int counter = 0;
foreach(Guid g in Array)
{
s+= "GuidPrimaryKey.Equals(@" counter.ToString() + ") OR";
p += "Array[" counter.ToString() + "],";
counter++;
}

s = s.remove(s.length - 3, 3);
p = p.remove(p.length - 1, 1);

data = data.Where(s,p);
```

This gives me the error message: No Property or field '1' exists in type 'DynamicClass1'

Any ideas?  I need to have the where clause build the query to check to see if the primary key (GuidPrimaryKey) exists in the list of keys (Guid[]).

Comment: Can you just do data.Any and use the expressions you know work?

Comment: @EricScherrer isn't the Any clause in Dynamic Linq Contains?  If so, that does not work as stated above.

Comment: data.any will return true if the dynamic expression finds any matches. So if you put data = data.any("GuidPrimaryKey.Equals(@0) OR GuidPrimaryKey.Equals(@1),array[0], array[1]); that might work. If you include the objects you are trying to query I will take a closer look in VS.

Comment: @EricScherrer I will give that a shot, however there are over 5,000 keys depended upon the criteria building the query so I need to have the parameters built in either a look as a variable or as an array.  Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: You've got it backwards.  The guid doesn't contain the array, you want to know if the array contains the GUID.  I'm not familiar with dynamic linq, but just a really wild guess, try: `data = data.where("@0.Contains(GuidPrimaryKey)",array);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works in the standard Dynamic Linq library, but I just tried this is [my open-source version](https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic), and it works well:

```
var data = data.Where("GuidPrimaryKey in @0", array);
```

This also works:

```
var data = data.Where("@0.Contains(GuidPrimaryKey)", array);
```

Here is a full unit test I wrote to confirm this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExpressionTests_ContainsGuid()
{
    //Arrange

    //Generate some users with Id fields of type Guid
    var userList = User.GenerateSampleModels(5, false); 
    var userQry = userList.AsQueryable();

    //Generate a list of values that will fail.
    var failValues = new List<Guid>() { 
        new Guid("{22222222-7651-4045-962A-3D44DEE71398}"), 
        new Guid("{33333333-8F80-4497-9125-C96DEE23037D}"), 
        new Guid("{44444444-E32D-4DE1-8F1C-A144C2B0424D}") 
    };

    //Add a valid Guid so that this list will succeed.
    var successValues = failValues.Concat(new[] { userList[0].Id }).ToArray();


    //Act
    var found1 = userQry.Where("Id in @0", successValues);
    var found2 = userQry.Where("@0.Contains(Id)", successValues);
    var notFound1 = userQry.Where("Id in @0", failValues);
    var notFound2 = userQry.Where("@0.Contains(Id)", failValues);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(userList[0].Id, found1.Single().Id);
    Assert.AreEqual(userList[0].Id, found2.Single().Id);
    Assert.IsFalse(notFound1.Any());
    Assert.IsFalse(notFound2.Any());
}
```